# Check if data is available before using recv()

Tags: winsock, blocking, recv

Is there a way you can use select() on an single socket, without involving fd_set?

I want to make sure there is something to read before using recv() so it doesn't block. Alternatively use recv() if it immediately can return when there is nothing to read in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

The only way to use `select()` without involving at least one `fd_set` is to supply 3 `nullptr`s (`NULL`s) to `select` which effectively turns the `select` call into a `sleep` using the `timeout` argument.